# Connecting to an "online" server through java ServerSocket

Tags: java, serversocket

Is it possible to connect to a server like "www.google.com" for example server side. Not actually connecting through google.com but that is the idea.

`ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0, 50, InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"));`

This code returns null, I am new to this connection related stuff so I don't know exactly what that would be meaning.

This is the code I have currently for setting up the server, it works fine when using localhost, but I am unsure on how to continue with an actual domain and server so anyone can connect and communicate.

If it isn't possible to set up a server like that, what is the best way to implement and I am trying to do.

Comment: You can't connect to *anything* with a `ServerSocket`. Use a `Socket`.

Comment: let me clarify, I am trying to find a way for the client to connect to my server from anywhere, instead of using a localhost ip. Don't know if that made any more sense.

Comment: What does google.com have to do with that?  You can't seriously imagine that Google allows anybody to bind sockets to their IP addresses, or that it's even possible under TCP. You're almost always better off not binding a `ServerSocket` to any specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

you can open raw sockets to whatever you want, but a `ServerSocket` is if you want to **be** a server, not if you want to connect to one; you'd use normal `Socket` for that.

sockets is for raw TCP/IP. You run some service on top of it. For example, HTTP or HTTPS, which is what the web runs on, is built on top of it.

I really doubt you want to write an HTTP client just for www.google.com, it's rather complicated. Fortunately, java has one built in. Don't use `Socket`, use `HttpClient`.

[See the java HTTP client tutorial here](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html).

Comment: A TCP socket is not a raw socket. Don't misuse standard terminology.